# Spring Integration File Splitter Memory Usage

Tags: spring-integration

1. Does `split()` operation on `File object` buffer and execute each line or do all lines get loaded in memory at once? This is to understand the memory usage if the file happens to contain 100,000+ lines.
2. Is it fair for a `transformer` to return `void`? The usage is to compute a few logic from the payload & headers then add the computed value to headers. Is there a better way?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource(), p -> p.poller(pollerSpec()))
                        .enrichHeaders(Collections.singletonMap(ERROR_CHANNEL, appErrorChannel))
                        .split() // process file by file
                        .log(INFO, message -> "Started File: " + message.getHeaders().get("file_name"))
                        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction("foo", m -> integrationUtil.constructFoo())) // fooobject
                        .split(fileSplitterSpec()) // split file lines
                            .filter(payload -> !(payload instanceof FileSplitter.FileMarker), e -> e.discardChannel("aggregatorChannel"))
                            .log(INFO, message -> "Payload: " + message.getPayload())
                            .transform(barTransformer)
                        .channel("aggregatorChannel")
                        .aggregate(new FileAggregator())
                        .log(INFO, message -> "Completed File: " + message.getHeaders().get("file_name"))
                        .aggregate()
                        .log(INFO, message -> "All Files Processed")
                        // .handle(null)
                        .get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that was really a purpose of the `FileSplitter`. It's internal logic is based on the `FileIterator`, which reads line by line an emits it to the splitter output channel.

No, the transformer cannot return `void`. That's not its purpose. Sounds more like an `enrichHeaders()` is better for you. Messages are immutable and you just cannot modify the current message for possible further logic. You build a new message with new data (or header) and emit it as a reply downstream the flow.

Comment: 2. Can you please share a sample for the enrichHeaders in DSL which has access to payload and headers? thx

Comment: `.enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction("foo", m -> m...)`

Comment: Thanq v much, got to say have become a fan of Spring Integration :)

Comment: Why is my `aggregate()` never called, I have ensured the `headers` are preserved in the `transformer`? pls check

Comment: We need to know what your `transformer.transform()` does.

Comment: pls see the UPDATE section. Any chance it is because there are 2 'split()' ?

Comment: What is your `fileSplitter` configuration? It indeed may not populate sequence details headers with a `markers = true`. You may need to look into the `FileAggregator` if you rely on the file markers: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#file-aggregator

Comment: `org.springframework.integration.file.splitter.FileSplitter' is used to set the first line of the file in the header, so that the headers can be used to construct xml tags for each subsequent (value) lines. Pls see UPDATE section

Comment: Well, again: the default aggregator cannot gather the group because `FileSplitter` does not populate a `sequenceSize` header. It cannot with an iterator. You need to revise your aggregator for different completion strategy or see if `FileAggregator` can help you.

Comment: Thanks, It worked now after following as mentioned in the link shared.

Comment: Is there a way to know the completion of the outer split, ie., when all files are processed?

Comment: You cannot know that. The `fileReadingMessageSource` does not return a list of files. It does poll files from the dir one by one and send them as individual messages. If you have a task for a list of files, then `fileReadingMessageSource` is not for you. You need to look into some custom solution based on the `File.listFiles()` or though.

Comment: OK, let me see if my `PseudoTransactionManager` configured with the Poller helps with that, thank you again !!

Comment: Therefore your first splitter is just pass-through. It produces only one file - the one it receives.